# File importer/ File Mover methods are not getting invoked when using Form swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift3, swiftui-form

even though the binding properties in fileMover are set to true. file mover is not getting executed. Below is the sample code i have used. Any leads will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

```
var body: SomeView {
    
    Form {
        Section {
            HStack {
                //some view logic
            }.fileMover(isPresented: $viewModel.shouldStartFileExport,
                        file: viewModel.targetURL) { result in
                print("result")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ViewModel {
    @State var shouldStartFileExport = false
    @State var targetURL: URL = //some URL
}
```

Comment: Is "result" getting printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use "@State" inside "struct ViewModel" like you did, they are for views.

There are many ways to have your variables changing, here I show you can use "ObservableObject", or you can simply use "@State" in the view.

```
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var shouldStartFileExport = false
        @Published var targetURL = URL(string: "somefileurl")!
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
    //    @State var shouldStartFileExport = false
    //    @State var targetURL = URL(string: "somefileurl")!
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                HStack {
                    Button("fileMover test") { viewModel.shouldStartFileExport = true }
                }
            }
        }
        .fileMover(isPresented: $viewModel.shouldStartFileExport, file: viewModel.targetURL) { result in
            print("\n-----> result <-----\n")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: this way I am able to import. But my question is when you try using form and section. Then mover is not getting executed.   Can you check with form and section like below. Form { Section  { Vstack }.filemover.

Comment: I have updated my answer, by putting ".fileMover(...)" outside the Form. This works well for me.

Comment: Thanks. its working now after moving file mover coder to root view.. 
Form instead of section or vStack